# Should H1 tags on all pages in a section of the site be the same?

Tags: seo, html, h1

When navigating to various pages within the "About Us" section of our website, should the H1 tags, be the same or different for SEO?

For example we have a page with "about us" as the `H1`. There are navigation links, that when clicked, take you another page like "things we do."

#### Alternative 1

The `H1` of that page is "things we do."

#### Alternative 2

The `H1` of that page is also "about us" and "things we do" is set as the `H2`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if your asking about two different alternatives/solutions, or simply identifying two separate pages. But maybe this will help.

`Hx` tags are intended to act as a content outline, helping both your reader and bots understand your content.  It is not uncommon, for the title of a page to be an H1 tag.  In fact, many Wordpress plugins make the title of the page an H1 tag.

```
<h1>About us</h1>
We're a growing company with 5 employees in the Silicone Valley.
<h2>Things we do</h2>
<h3>Widget 1</h3> We are the leading producer of widget 1...
 For more info <a href="example.com/widget1">about widget one</a> be sure to read this
<h3>Widget 2</h3> We produce widget 2 for ...
<h3>Widget 3</h3>  We also make widget 3...
```

Presumably, your "about us" page, truly is more about your company, and not about your products/services.

Then, if you have additional information that is worthy of it's own page (such as widget 1) then it is perfectly fine to have that dedicated page use `<h1>Widget 1</h1>` for it's title page as that tells bots(including Google) that the main content of this page is about 'Widget 1'.

To optimize your SEO, it may be helpful to find another way to describe widget 1.  The more synonyms you can use, the more clues you are giving bots to the content that might answer a user's query.

I have nothing to back this up, but I'm convinced that Google takes several weeks of testing users' responses to new pages.  Google wants to determine if the query the user asked and the page content, answered the user's question.  I'm guessing this requires sending a sample of user queries toward your page and measuring certain user responses, including bounce rate.

All that being said, write your content, and your headings for user clarity, but also to tell bots how your content is structured.

Comment: "about us" and "things we do" are two different pages in the "about us" section of the website.

Answer (score 2):

Hx tags are crucial for structuring your content, serving as indicators for search engines and website visitors about content hierarchy and relevance. The H1 tag, in particular, is a powerful indicator of a page's primary subject.

For SEO optimization, consider the following guidelines:

Single H1 Use: Each page should have only one H1 tag, reflecting the main topic or purpose of the page.

Content Consistency: The H1's content should be representative of the main content on the page. If the page is dedicated to "things we do," then the H1 should be "things we do". Having "about us" as H1 and "things we do" as H2 might confuse both bots and visitors, especially if the page is mainly about the things you do.

Content Hierarchy: Maintain a clear hierarchy with your Hx tags. The H1 is the main topic, with H2s, H3s, etc., acting as subtopics and subsections. If "things we do" is a subcategory of "about us", then it makes sense as an H2. But if it's a separate page with its main focus, it should have its own H1.

Clarity for Users: Beyond SEO, think about user experience. Header tags help visitors understand and navigate the content. Use them in ways that make sense and facilitate reading.

Synonyms and Variations: When covering similar topics across different pages, vary the language and use synonyms. This helps avoid redundancy and caters to different types of search queries.

In conclusion, if subpages under "About us" are distinct and warrant their own spotlight, they should have their own relevant H1 to the page's content. If they are more like subsections of the "About us" page, then using H2s, H3s, etc., is more fitting.

Answer (score 0):

No, H1 tags on all pages in a section of the site should generally be unique and reflect the specific content or topic of each individual page for SEO and user experience.